# Klein-Gordon equation in curved space time

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, klein-gordon-equation

The Klein-Gordon equation in curved spacetime has the following form:

$$\left (\square+m^2 \right)\Phi=\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}
\partial_{\mu}\left(\sqrt{-g}g^{\mu\nu} \partial_{\nu} \right)+m^2\right]\Phi=0$$

In the case of the Schwarzschild Metric, $g_{00}$ and $g_{11}$ are dimensionless, while $g_{22}$ and $g_{33}$ are not. However, in the equation we need every term to have the same dimensions. What I have missed?

Comment: There is more than one way to think about units in general relativity. For a detailed discussion, see section 5.11 of my GR book, http://www.lightandmatter.com/genrel/ . *in the equation we need every term to have the same dimensions* It's not clear to me why you think this is in danger of being violated. Note that the derivatives also have units.

Comment: This form of the Klein-Gordon equation seems ugly to me. I could be wrong, but it seems to me that if you just take the flat-spacetime version and replace partial derivatives with covariant derivatives, you ought to get something much prettier.

Answer (score 3):

Every component of the metric is dimensionless, if you use rectilinear coordinates. $g_{22}$ and $g_{33}$ only have dimensions if you are using curvilinear coordinates (probably spherical, in this case). In that case, the $\partial_2$ and $\partial_3$ also have correspondingly different dimensions than $\partial_0$ and $\partial_1$.

Comment: Yes, it is about spherical coordiates, and derivatives indeed has different dimensions, but they do not cancel out... And we still have different dimensions for r in terms of equation

Comment: @BekaModrekiladze The difference in units between the derivatives and metric components do indeed cancel in spherical coordinates. Remember that the raised indices on the metric tensor indicate that the *inverse* matrix to the metric is being used, so the units of $g_{22}$ and $g_{33}$ (which are length, in spherical coordinates) should be inverted when plugging $g^{22}$ and $g^{33}$ into the equation.